# Can someone characterize this property?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In a book of trigonometry there is the next (very visual) excercise:[image]

Given the triangle in the image (the left one) justify the next : why the angles that aren´t given in the triangles are of 45°?

I proceed the next way, we draw a tangent, and to this tangent  we trace a perpendicular line, 
so if this is represented as in the image of the right we have $a+b=90$, $c+d=90$, $b+c=90$, so we have $a+b=c+d=b+c$ and with this I thought we can conclude $a=b=c=d$, but I have not proved that (only I made a sketchy incomplete attempt), in that stage ,(I realized that this "behaviour" is the heart of the problem) then I see the problem through the eyes of abstraction and I ignored the other information of this problem, and I reduce the question to the next: It is true that if $a+b=c+d=b+c$ then $a=b=c=d$? so I realized that in my sketchy proof I used subtraction and the operation was addition and that the behaviours were similar to that of groups, and I concluded that this behaviour have a general setting in groups, but I can't proceed to conclude in what groups this hold, So could please someone characterize the groups in which $\forall~ a,b,c,d \in G : id_G \not=a,b,c,d, ab=cd=bc\Rightarrow a=b=c=d$?

So much thanks for all!

Comment: Intuitively, the $90^\circ$ angle shows the opposite segment is a diameter, but it could slide around the circle and still be a diameter.  That would alter all the angles $a,b,c,d$ subject to the sum relations you have found.

Comment: The implication holds in all abelian groups, and won't necessarily hold in non-abelian groups.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks! Can you provide me a reference to a proof of the statement or prove it please? Much thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the system of equations. You get $b=d$ and $a=c$, if the group is abelian. If the group is not abelian, you cannot deduce anything like that.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen so many thanks! those equalities are the only thing that I can do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This fails for every nontrivial group.  Suppose $a=c$ are nontrivial and let $b,d$ be the identity.  Then $ab=cd=bc$ but $a,c\not= b,d$.

So, if the property holds for all $a,b,c,d\in G$, then $G$ is the trivial group.

---

Taking just the $ab=bc$ part, we left multiply to obtain $b^{-1}ab=c$.  Thus we may pick any two distinct elements in a conjugacy class to be $a$ and $c$, so this cannot hold for any group which has nontrivial conjugacy classes - that is, all nonabelian groups.  Yet even in abelian groups, left multiplying by $b^{-1}$ this becomes $a=b^{-1}cd=c$ whence $a=b^{-1}dc$ whence $1=b^{-1}d$ so $b=d$.  So if we can find any nontrivial $a\not= b$ we are done.  So assuming that none of $a,b,c,d$ are the identity gets us only that the property holds in $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: Thanks! but what about if we suppose a,b,c,d are not the identity?

Comment: @EduardoAlanDávalosPeña See my updated answer.